# What may cause a GeoRequest:Can't connect to source; error in Expression Engine?

Tags: php, google-maps, expressionengine

One of the clients the company I work for uses Expression Engine for their custom site. It was built roughly 2+ years before I hired in, and it's our only EE site. The person who built is is no longer working here, so fixing/updating the site has been a task for everyone involved.

They utilize a location search feature that seems to be common in EE, so I doubt it's custom. It ties into Google Maps. The initial page loads fine, with several locations, and when I navigate to individual locations, those pages load fine. The search_results page, however, throws this error: **GeoRequest : Can't connect to source;**

I've Googled this error, and most everything I come across says to check if the version of PHP  has changed on the server. I know for a fact that it has not. Nothing on the site has changed. We log everything, and nothing has been touched for over a month. It just suddenly stopped working.

I feel pretty blind here. Any common things that contribute to this specific error? Any EE experts with ideas of where to best track down error sources?

Update: it appears as though MX Google Map for EE is being used. Hope this helps.

Comment: You might want to post this to the ExpressionEngine specific StackExchange site for a faster response: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that the version of MX Google Maps you have installed may be using a now outdated version of the Google Maps API. First thing you might look at is in your add-ons menu in the control panel, look at the version number of the MX Google Maps add-on you have installed and compare it to the [latest version on devot-ee.com](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-google-maps).  The add-on developer offers support through [his own support site](http://support.addons.mx).

Comment: It was. I spoke with the creator of MX Google Maps and he helped me implement a patch. Thanks for the reply, though!